# How to make maven goal visible in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to Maven and IntelliJ. I can run `mvn test-compile` from the command line fine, but I want to make it an entry in the Maven Lifecycle section of IntelliJ, as below.

Currently I have to either do the 'test' or 'package' option, but ideally I simply want to compile everything in my tests folder.

Is this possible? I thought it might be an explicit entry in the pom file, but searching I couldn't find anything to help.

[image]

Comment: came across this link similar to your question but looks like there is no easy way - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206944425-add-Maven-phase-or-goal-to-the-Maven-integration-in-IDEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Plugins -> compiler -> compiler:testCompile

[image: 1]

2. Or disable **Show Basic Phases Only** option in [Maven tool window settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html#toolbar):
   [image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thanks that works. The first option was just too detailed but the second was a good compromise. It would be nice if these could be added to the LifeCycle, but it's better than nothing :)